# How do foldr and zipWith (:) work together?

Tags: haskell, fold, zipwith

I'm new to Haskell, and I've come across the following code that baffles me:

```
foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
```

It produces the following result, which after playing around with it, I'm not entirely sure why:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

I'm under the impression that `(:)` prepends items to a list, and that `(repeat [])` produces an endless amount of empty lists `[]`, and that `foldr` takes a function, an item, and a list, and condenses the list by consecutively applying the function to each item in the list along with the results.

That is to say, I intuitively understand how the following code produces a result of 10:

```
foldr (+) 1 [2,3,4]
```

But, I'm not at all sure why `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])` takes a list of lists and produces another list of lists with items grouped by their original inner indices.

Any explanation would be enlightening.

Comment: In your `(+)` example, which element gets added to 1? Similarly in your full example, which element gets zipped with `repeat []`?

Comment: Hopefully the answers given have explained this for you, but I want to add that the "magic" here is the `zipWith (:)`, which takes a list of elements and a list of lists and prepends each element to the corresponding list. Eg. `zipWith (:) [1,2,3] [[4],[5],[6]]` is `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple. `foldr` is defined so that

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

thus,

```
foldr f z [a,b,c,...,n] = f a (f b (f c (...(f n z)...)))
```

Or, here,

```
foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
=
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] 
  ( foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) [[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]] )
=
...
=
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] 
  ( zipWith (:) [4,5,6]
      ( zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] 
          ( foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) [] )))
=
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] 
  ( zipWith (:) [4,5,6]
      ( zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] 
          ( repeat [] )))
=
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] 
  ( zipWith (:) [4,5,6]
      ( zipWith (:) [ 7, 8, 9,10] 
                    [[],[],[],[],[],[],....] ))
=
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] 
  ( zipWith (:) [ 4,  5,  6 ]
                [[7],[8],[9],[10]] )
=
zipWith (:) [ 1   , 2   , 3   ] 
            [[4,7],[5,8],[6,9]]
```

And that's that.

<sub>*(Next on the menu, `traverse ZipList [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]`... :) or maybe later.)*</sub>

---

As for the other example, it is

```
foldr (+) 1 [2,3,4] 
= 2 + foldr (+) 1 [3,4] 
= 2 + (3 + foldr (+) 1 [4]) 
= 2 + (3 + (4 + foldr (+) 1 [])) 
= 2 + (3 + (4 + 1))
= 2 + (3 + 5)
= 2 + 8
= 10
```

because `+` is *strict* in both of its arguments.

`zipWith` is not strict in both arguments, nor is the `(:)`, so the first sequence should be taken as an illustration only. The actual forcing will occur in the top-down order, not bottom-up. For instance,

```
> map (take 1) . take 1 $ zipWith (:) (1 : undefined) (repeat undefined)
[[1]]
```

fully in accordance with

```
map (take 1) . take 1 $ zipWith (:) (1 : undefined) (repeat undefined)
=
map (take 1) . take 1 $ zipWith (:) (1 : undefined) (undefined : repeat undefined)
=
map (take 1) . take 1 $ (1 : undefined) : zipWith (:) undefined (repeat undefined)
=
map (take 1) $ (1 : undefined) : take 0 (zipWith (:) undefined (repeat undefined))
=
map (take 1) $ (1 : undefined) : []
=
map (take 1) [(1 : undefined)]
=
[take 1 (1 : undefined)]
=
[1 : take 0 undefined]
=
[1 : []]
=
[[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

So using the intuition that `foldr` folds the list from the right (which is not the recursive definition) you get the following in the easy case:

```
foldr (+) 1 [2,3,4]
foldr (+) (4 + 1) [2,3]
foldr (+) (3 + 4 + 1) [2]
foldr (+) (2 + 3 + 4 + 1) []
(2 + 3 + 4 + 1)
10
```

Let's do the same in your example and considering the initial element `repeat [] == [[],[],[],[], …]`

```
foldr (zipWith (:)) ([[],[],[],[], ...]) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]] 
foldr (zipWith (:)) (zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] [[],[],[],[], ...]) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

wait a min. Lets develop `zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] [[],[],[],[], ...]`

```
zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] [[],[],[],[], ...] -- apply the funciton (:) pairwise
[7:[], 8:[], 9:[], 10:[]]                 -- we get rid of the infinite list at this point.
[[7],[8],[9],[10]]
```

From here we can easily follow the rest of the code

```
foldr (zipWith (:)) ([[],[],[],[], ...]) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]] 
foldr (zipWith (:)) (zipWith (:) [7,8,9,10] [[],[],[],[], ...]) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
foldr (zipWith (:)) ([[7],[8],[9],[10]]) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
foldr (zipWith (:)) (zipWith (:) [4,5,6] [[7],[8],[9],[10]]) [[1,2,3]]
foldr (zipWith (:)) (zipWith (:) [1,2,3] [[4:7],[5:8],[6:9]) []
zipWith (:) [1,2,3] [[4:7],[5:8],[6:9]
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Notice that this is not the proper definition of `foldr` and we are evaluating the results inmediately instead of lazily (as haskell does), but this is only for the sake of understanding.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. it must follow `foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)`.

Comment: It is not correct, and I say It in the very first ans last line. My purpose was to give the intuition more than the actual definition which I think It can be missleading. But your answer was approved which doesn't prove my point at all hahaha